# Calling a class method dynamically

Tags: c#

**Edit: In real life i don't have a Book class. This is just an example to be clear. Real problem really needs reflection to solve it.**

Suppose that I have some classes:

Book, Apple, Door.

```
class Book
{
   ...
   public decimal getPrice()
   {...}
   public string getTitle()
   {...}
   public decimal getAuthor()
   {...}
}
```

and something same for other classes.

May i call a class method dynamically from a string:

```
Book myBook = new Book("Title", "Author", 44);

string title = runMethod(myBook, "getTitle");
```

Comment: Could I ask as to how this would be used?

Comment: Yes, please. I feel like there is something in this question I am missing.

Comment: Don't you ever need refrection ? I used it in Java and glad C# has it too. and it is a long story where to use it. but it is really needed. Example above is just an example to explain myself. Of course i will not use it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this, using reflection:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var b = new Book("Book Title", 2342);

    Console.WriteLine(CallMethod(b, "GetTitle", "Not Found"));
}

public static K CallMethod<T,K>(T a, string method, K defaultOjb)
{
    var t = a.GetType();

    var mi = t.GetMethod(method);
    if (mi == null) return defaultOjb;

    var ret=mi.Invoke(a, new object[] {});

    return (K) ret;
}
}

public class Book
{
private readonly string _title;
private readonly decimal _price;

public decimal GetPrice()
{
    return _price;
}
public string GetTitle()
{
    return _title;
}

public Book(string title, decimal price)
{
    _title = title;
    _price = price;
}
}
```

Comment: I accept it and your all answers in 2010 will be accepted :P ( Thanks it really helped a lot )

Answer (score 5):

You can do this via [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx).

```
Book myBook = new Book("Title", "Author", 44); 

string title = (string) myBook.GetType().GetMethod("getTitle").Invoke(myBook, null);
```

Comment: That is a pretty kluggy way of getting something back.

Comment: In this case, it's completely silly.  There are times when reflection is very useful, though - and this at least demonstrates the types and methods required.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup reflection and MethodInfo.  I believe that will lead you down the path you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers are correct in mentioning reflection.

However, unless your true question is very different from your example it's unnecessary.

Judging from your example you could simply call it directly:

```
string title = mybook.getTitle();
```

If the point is that you don't know and don't want to care what specific object you're being given you can either use a base class, or an interface.

```
public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Type { get; }
    float Price { get; }
}
```

Make your classes implement IProduct and you're guaranteed that your classes will have implemented the properties or functions you've required, and that they will be public no matter whether you're dealing with "Book", "Apple", or "Door".

```
    public void OutputProductsToConsole(List<IProduct> products)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(products[i].Name + ": " + products[i].Price);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No this is not relevant with my question. Sorry i know what interface is. What i really need is calling a method from a string.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with reflection, but in the example, it would be simpler to just call the method directly:

```
string title = myBook.getTitle();
```

Comment: This is what I would have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating your new Book class with the property values. Are you not assigning the values so you can get them back later?

```
public class Book
{

    private string _title;
    private decimal _price;
    private string _author;

    public Book(string title, decimal price, string author);
    {
        _title = title;
        _price = price;
        _author = author;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _title;
        }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return _price;
        }
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get
        {
            return _author;
        }
    }

}
```

Better yet, if these methods are common to all your classes create an interface and inherit that in your classes.